# Angular not updating ngclass based on $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a slider (using angular-material) which is bout to a Controller As variable (avm.itemsIndex) which is used in an ng-class on an ng-repeat list.

So each item in the ng-repeat has:

```
ng-class="{ 
            active : avm.itemsIndex == $index, 
            selected : avm.selecting==item.name, 
            left : avm.itemsIndex == $index+1 ,
            left2 : avm.itemsIndex == $index+2,
            right : avm.itemsIndex == $index-1,
            right2 : avm.itemsIndex == $index-2
        }"
```

So no two items should ever have .active because they are all comparing $index to avm.itemsIndex. Nor should any item have both .active and .left, .left 2 etc

The problem is that if I drag the slider quickly so that it updates avm.itemsIndex in quick succession then several items will have the .active, and some might have .active and .left, .left2 etc.

It seems like not all the item classes get updated whenever avm.itemsIndex changes.

Does anyone know how I can solve this, or even debug it?

Comment: You must post more of your code in order for us to check on the possible causes.

Comment: There isn't really any more to show. As I said, the variable avm.itemsIndex is bound to a material slider. As the slider is slid the value changes. This value is changing correctly.

It seems that ng-class is not updating the classes on all the items every time avm.itemsIndex is changed, especially if it is changed is rapid succession by sliding the slider quickly. If I dump {{avm.itemsIndex}} and {{$index}} in the view they are correct. The problem is ng-class not updating all item classes in the repeat.

Answer (score 0):

To debug just dump the values using `{{ avm.itemsIndex == $index+2 }}` I use controller as syntax a lot. Have you tried making `avm.itemsIndex` a function instead of a property? I had better joy with binding when using functions.

So instead of:

```
this.itemsIndex = 5;
```

You would have:

```
this.itemsIndex = function() {
    return 5;
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
avm.itemsIndex() === $index+1; // notice parantheses
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried making avm.itemsIndex a function, but with the same result.

The odd thing is that if I dump the variables in each item the values show correctly, but ng-class is still getting the classes wrong, so that {{avm.itemsIndex === $index}} shows 'false' but it still has the .active class from: active : avm.itemsIndex === $index

Comment: try ...active : avm.itemsIndex($index) ... and get the function to return a boolean - check that $index is the expected value inside the function and that the function returns the expected boolean value

Comment: I tried that, same problem. I even tried not using ng-class and just put {{ avm.itemsIndex === $index? 'active' : '' }} etc directly in class=" " and also dumped it in each item content to display the values. In the item content it is correct but in the class it gets muddled. I wonder if it's a bowser issue that prevents updating class="" so rapidly?

Anyhow, I've bound the slider to a different variable and use $inteval at 200 ms to update the avm.itemsIndex value. Anything less that 200 causes mixups. It's horribly hacky, but it works. Very weird problem.

Comment: @user2248331 Have you tried binding the ng-class to a function rather than using the object syntax? E.g. doing the logic in the function and returning the respective class name?

Comment: James, yes I did. What eventually worked was putting a slight timeout (250ms) on updating the tag class. It seems to be a browser issue more than an angular issue, and related to updating a tag attribute too quickly

Answer (score 0):

What eventually worked was putting a slight timeout (20ms) on updating the tag class. It seems to be a browser issue more than an angular issue, and related to updating a tag attribute too quickly